# Exec a complex stored procedure in MS SQL using Pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to create a program that upload an excel table to SQL server and run a procedure of that takes the table as an input. The procedure is pretty complex with declare statement using injected variable, and dynamic variable (e.g. derived from injected variable, or select the latest table in the database). I tried several things but the proc were not executed.

```
Server='IP address'
Database='database name'
Driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

date = '20221220'
MONTH = '202211' 

db = pyodbc.connect(driver=Driver, server=Server, Trusted_Connection='yes')
dbc = db.cursor()

stored_proc = f"exec db..proc @date = '{date}',@Month='{MONTH}'"
dbc.execute(stored_proc)

#I also tried this, but it did not worked either 
#dbc.execute(f"db..proc {date}, {MONTH}")
#dbc.execute("db..proc ?,?", [date,MONTH])
```

I expected that the procedure was successfully executed and data are updated. However, no error were shown in python terminal, but data in the needed SQL table were not updated either. I suspect that pyodbc can run select, insert into, update, ... statements, but not the declare statement.

Can any one help me with this?
Many thanks

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74884130/edit) your question to at least include the signature of your stored procedure. It's difficult for anybody to provide a correct answer to your question when the stored procedure's parameter names and parameter data types are unknown.

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON`  to the proc if you haven't already done so. The `DONE_IN_PROC` TDS messages (rowcounts) can cause issues with some APIs.

Comment: @vtm.0811 checked an article , below 2 formats are mentioned ...try the ODBC syntax please.                                                                                                                                                  # SQL Server format
cursor.execute("exec sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')")

# ODBC format
cursor.execute("{call sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')}")